# 'Fancybox' Lightbox Failing to Produce Dark Background

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Under 'Gallery' on http://tuba-archery.com

I don't get a dark background when I select an image from the array of pics.

I haven't touched anything to do with opacity!

jquery.fancybox.css and jquery.fancybox.js are the main files involved and I know very little at this stage of my Javascript/Jquery learning. These two files are quite long and I don't know how to attach or add them in a scrollbox.

Can anyone shed any light on how to amend the javascript or css file to get a dark background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open fancybox.css

Find line

```
 .fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    /* background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');*/ change this line to
    background: url('images/fancybox_overlay.png');

}
```

Your images are in images folder and css in main folder. You need to edit all `url()` in fancybox.css for all other images to work

**or**

add

```
.fancybox-overlay {
 background: url('images/fancybox_overlay.png');
}
```

in style.css and load style.css after fancybox.css. This way in future if you upgrade fancybox.css. The changes will be there.

Comment: You don;t have to edit the original js or css files because you will loose your changes if you upgrade. You can always override the default settings within your custom css file. Ideally the fancybox images/sprite should be placed under the same folder as the css file

Comment: I've added "background: url('images/fancybox_overlay.png');" to the end of my styles.css